# loosing pointers on vector of struct instances, with pointers in the struct

Tags: c++

Not sure if the title is right or not, but here it goes:

If I have for example the following structure:

```
struct strA{
    int x;

    strA(int x);
}

strA::strA(int x){
    this->x = x;
}
```

And another structure that uses a pointer to the previous one:

```
#include strA

struct strB{
    int y;
    strA *var_strA;

    strB(int y);
    ~strB(){
        delete var_strA;
    }
};

strB::strB(int y){
    this->y = y;
    var_strA = new strA(123);
}
```

Then if I do from the main aplication a vector of strB items:

```
std::vector<strB> vectB;

main(){
    strB *itemB = new strB(456);
    vectB.push_back(*itemB);
    delete itemB;

    //more code
}
```

If I try to access the var_strA on the item in the vector, is empty. And also, I get an error when by deleting the item on the vector, since the destructor tries to delete var_strA again.

Comming from Java... I'm really getting lost with the damn pointers.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean `delete itemB` rather than `delete strB`?

Comment: Why is var_strA even a pointer? Why is itemB even a pointer? Think about it. Java forces you to create objects dynamically. Java forces an extra level of indirection w.r.t. objects. C++ does not. You need to learn to appreciate that. Also, get one or more decent C++ books. For the purpose of learning and using C++, you should forget everything you know about Java. Trust me. I've been there and done that.

Comment: yes, there is no need that var_strA be pointer, but if itemB is not a pointer, how do I create new objects with the constructor? cause
strB itemB = new strB(....) doesn work

Comment: nevermind, already figured out, and also checked an old c++ book I had gathering dust... :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator on that pointer-holding type, i.e. follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). Here's a great resource here on SO: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)